# Cant ssh or see website after home ip change, but can get http 404 and 403

Tags: nginx, ip, connection, http-status-code-404

I have a server in a client office, this server has a website running on nginx. A few days ago my home router and ip changed, and now I can’t ssh to the server, or see the website, the browser stays in a never-ending state of “thinking”, but if I go to specific urls that return 404 and 403 codes I get the response and the page loads perfectly.

The ssh stays also in a never-ending state of thinking. I have no firewall running at home computer or router, and there is no ip blocked at the server. I can access the website and ssh perfectly from another location.

Is this pattern of allowing 404 and 403 but no 200 codes related to any kind of "firewall" between me and the server?

*Edit to respond to CB40:*
I captured traffic from another location, I did connect simultaniously to the office server and my home , and I sended a request to the page from my home computer, and saw that at the office server, the packet was being sent through port 80 with the 200 code to my home computer, but it was being re-delivered constantly.

Comment: What are the first two octets of you home WAN IP address?

Comment: @RonMaupin They are 62 and 43

Comment: OK. I just wanted to see if you got changed to CGN (pretty common, lately), but those look like a public address range.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like access list on firewall or server at customer site seeing how when your IP changed problem started. Do you use dyn DNS? Is something trying to do reverse lookup?

Comment: No, and the problem exists using both the domain name and the ip address .

Comment: Is your new ip allowed through firewall? Did you capture traffic at wan and lan side at customer site to see if your getting through? Is it nat our one to one four your acces?

Comment: Yes it is allowed through firewall. I captured traffic and updated the question. Yes at home Im using nat.